# Find gradient & angle of inclination of the tangent where x = 3

Tags: calculus

> Differentiate f (x) = $x$$^2$ − 3$x$ − 6.Find the gradient and the angle of inclination  of the tangent at the point where $x$ = 3

I have already differentiated the beginning and got

2$x$ -3 but I am not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angle of inclination ( $\theta$ ) is just $tan^{-1}(m)$ ,where $m$ is the slope, so for your function the gradient (slope) at $x=3$ is $3$ and $\theta$ is $tan^{-1}(3)$ which is approximately $1.249$ radians.
The reason for why $m$=tan($\theta$) is because $m$=$\large rise\over run$ but that is the same as $$sin(\theta) \over cos(\theta)$$  If you draw a right angled triangle .